# Access VBA error while Storing into table doesn't trigger "On Error"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting errors storing into the table, but the On Error isn't triggering. On the line db.Execute I'll get a constraint error, but rather than trigger an error, the code continues like it's successful. When I get out of the routine, I know there's an error because 0 is passed back, but I don't know what the error is, so I end up having to come in with debug, capture the code and then try it directly in Access. Is there anyway I can get it to trigger the error? Here's my code (abbreviated):

```
Private Function storeHAP(list of arguments, ByRef db As DAO.Database) As Long
  Dim sql As String
  On Error GoTo foundError

  sql = "INSERT INTO HAPs (list of column names...) " + _
             "VALUES (list of values...)"
  db.Execute (sql)

  'This function will look up the record and return the primary key.
  'A value of 0 indicates it wasn't stored and will force an exit in
  'the main routine.
  storeHAP = lookupHAP(list of arguments..., db)
  Exit Function
foundError:
  MsgBox "Error in storeHAP: " + CStr(Err) + ", " + Error(Err) + ". SQL: " + sql + "."
End Function 'storeHAP
```

Comment: How do you know there's a constraint error? Does it break if you do `db.Execute "foo"`? Unrelated, but 1) drop the parentheses around `(sql)`, and 2) you might find useful that the global `Err` object has `Number` and `Description` properties; using them would make the `foundError` code much less confusing, given `Error` used as a statement is a deprecated way of raising an error, and `Error` used as a function (like you have) is a roundabout way of retrieving the description for `Err.Number`, which is what you're actually giving it (`Number` being the *default property* of the `Err` object).

Comment: If I go into debug and do a print sql in the immediate window and then copy the sql into an Access query design, I get a constraint error, but it isn't sufficient to let me know where. It turns out, if I follow the answer below, I actually get enough information in my MsgBox to pinpoint where it is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx) (my emphasis):

> In a Microsoft Access workspace, if you provide a syntactically
>   correct SQL statement and have the appropriate permissions, ***the***
>   ***Execute method won't fail*** — even if not a single row can be modified
>   or deleted. Therefore, always use the dbFailOnError option when using
>   the Execute method to run an update or delete query. This option
>   generates a run-time error and rolls back all successful changes if
>   any of the records affected are locked and can't be updated or
>   deleted.

You need to specify the `dbFailOnError` option:

```
db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish the examples I'd worked off in the past had shown that. I'm going to be doing blanket updates of my systems to have this. I'm pretty sure my stuff is idiot proof, but that's only good enough until the next idiot comes around! :-)